# Angular 6 Router navigation not rendering child component in the destination component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, router-outlet

I have an Angular 6 application with a login component and a dashboard component.
Am trying to navigate to DashboardComponent on the login button click event.
DashboardComponent contains a child component called  WardComponent .
But while navigating the to the dashboard it render only the contents other than the child component ward.How can i render the dashboard component with child component it it after the login ?

Please see my component classes below

AppComponent

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

LoginComponent.ts

```
  export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  login() {
    this.router.navigate(["/dashboard/"]);
  }
}
```

DashboardComponent

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "dashboard",
  template: `
    haii u r in dashboard compo

    <div class="form-inline" style="padding: 40px;">
      <ward *ngFor="let ward of wards" [wardNumber]="ward"></ward>
    </div>
  `
})
export class DashboardComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

WardComponent.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "ward",
  template: `
    <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-header"></div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">{{ wardNumber + 1 }}</h2>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="checkIn()">check in</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="checkOut()">check Out</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class WardComponent {
  @Input() wardNumber: Number;
  checkedIn: boolean = false;
  constructor() {}

  checkIn() {
    console.log("checked in");
    this.checkedIn = true;
  }

  checkOut() {}
}
```

app.module.ts

```
  const indexRoutes: Route = {
  path: "",
  component: DashboardComponent
};
// for all invalid routers , it will redirect to login component
const fallbackRoutes = {
  path: "**",
  component: LoginComponent
};

const routes: Routes = [
  indexRoutes,

  {
    path: "dashboard",
    component: DashboardComponent
  },

  {
    path: "ward",
    component: WardComponent
  },

  fallbackRoutes
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WardComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Check the contents of  `wards` in `Dashboard`, that might not be populated

Comment: you are  right , i have added the  content of wards in wrong place, instead of  adding the  wards array in WardComponent , i have  put that  in AppComponent.thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of the content of ward component is not populated correctly .i have added the content of wards in wrong place, instead of adding the wards array in WardComponent , i have put that in AppComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `Routes` config like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "dashboard",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [{
      path: "ward",
      component: WardComponent
    }]
  },
  {
    path: "",
    pathMatch: "full",
    redirectTo: "/dashboard"
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    component: LoginComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({...})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

I've added a `pathMatch: 'full'` and a `redirectTo: '/dashboard'` to `path: ''`. I've also gotten rid of the `const`s and then added the routes for those `const`s to the `routes` `const` itself.

You'll also have to add a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to the template of the `DashboardComponent`

Comment: after adding the above snippet , its not  rendering the login component , instead it directly render the dashboard component . i tried by adding a indexroutes and it render the login component . but it still showing the same behaviour , not rendering the  child component ward even after adding the router-outlet

Comment: @AnsarSamad, one would ideally prevent the Dashboard path via a `CanActivate` guard to prevent unauthorized access to it. You can implement one and then check whether a user is logged in or not in the guard. If the user is not logged in, simply navigate the user to `/login` path.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Ward route to children array like

```
const routes: Routes = [
    indexRoutes,
    {
        path: "dashboard",
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children:[
        {
             path: "ward",
             component: WardComponent
        }]
    },
    fallbackRoutes
   ];
```

Comment: The question is already answered by OP himself posted some time ago. When posting an answer, please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.